# How to integrate zend library in codeigniter 2?

Tags: codeigniter, zend-framework, barcode

How to integrate the zendframework 2 library with codeigniter 2? I want to use barcode library from zendframework. I found [this](http://blog.ghostbilt.com/zend-barcodes-codeigniter/) tutorial and i follow it and i got the output that show anything. When i check the source code from browser and i check the image link it said "cannot be display because it contains errors". I don't know what is error. Can anyone know?

Comment: you need to turn on errors so we can see what PHP is getting hung up on:  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Show the code you're using & the url you're calling (I suspect this is happening because an error is being outputted along with the image which makes it a broken image).

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to integrate Zend libraries to Codeigniter Framework:

Just copy the libraries from Zend to the **third_party** folder in CI.

create a library in library folder of CI to initialize the **zend library** from **third_party** folder.

--library code--

```
class CI_Zend { 

    function load($class)
    {

    $path=(string) realpath( APPPATH.'third_party/zend') .'/'.$class . EXT;
        require_once($path) ;


    }
}
```

this will attach the **zend** library to the CI project......

You can download the dummy CI with zend from:

http://www.4shared.com/archive/-KJsvwoV/citar.html